# Exim & WHM - Run PHP Script on mail rejection

Tags: php, execute, whm, exim

I wrote a script to reject emails if they have zip attachments containing exe, js files..etc etc.. It worked successfully. I wrote the following script under acl_smtp_mime at WHM Exim Advanced Editor:

```
deny message = "This message might contain harmful files."
condition = ${if match{$mime_filename}{\N(?i)\.zip$\N}}
decode = default
condition = ${if match{${run{/usr/bin/unzip -l $mime_decoded_filename}}} {\N(?i)\.(com|js|pif|scr|lnk|exe)\n\N} }
```

I am trying to execute a PHP script that inserts a log entry in the databse regarding the rejected email but I failed.

I tried inserting this line at the end but it failed to run the script

```
continue = ${run{/usr/bin/php '/home/*hidden*/public_html/test.php $mime_decoded_filename'}{0}{1}}
```

When I run the PHP from the browser just for testing, it runs fine and creates a fake log. It seems I'm not calling the script correctly from EXIM. Emails are rejected successfully but the PHP file is not getting called

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run my php script using curl:

```
continue = ${run{/usr/bin/curl http://www.*****.com/test.php?fn=$mime_filename&sa=$sender_address&rf=$recipients}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think exim knows how to execute .php scripts. You could try to port that php script to perl. Exim on a cPanel/WHM server, by default, has the ability to run perl scripts. You might want to read exim documentation though regarding the php scripts...